# what video formats does flash support?

Tags: javascript, flash, video, codec

I want to add video upload support to my small school and after some research i came across sample code:

```
exec("ffmpeg -i ".$dynamic_path."/".$ moviepath."".$fileName." 
 -sameq -acodec mp3 -ar 22050 -ab 32 -f flv -s 320x240 ".$dynamic_path."/".$flvpath."myflv.flv");
```

I understand this will guarantee conversion, but am using shared hosting, so i would like to know what kind of format flash supports and is their any javascript/flash support to play video files without conversion.

thanks

Comment: flv certainly was most common, but we've spent the last 3yrs converting 1M+ videos to mp4 for the major educational video providers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what our company does for a living, and we have arrived at mp4 being the standard for nearly every highschool/college/university in the country - the definitive list can be seen here:

http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/supported-codecs-flash-player.html

The video player that they all seem to prefer is the JW Player, and it can be found at http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/.  Another is [Flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org/), though my experience on this one is limited.  The only difference between JWPlayer paid/free is the watermark, so you can experiment with this and Flowplayer before you buy one.

Comment: If you use the free version, yes, but the purchased license if very, very inexpensive, and the support folks are very responsive.  As well, it supports HTML5 along with embedable SWF objects, and javascript, so it' quite flexible for implementation.

Comment: i will purchase one and tick this as best answer, i noticed more goodies like fb, twitter share, etc... Can you please provide a coupon for the public exclusive for stackoverflow?

Comment: I would if I had any idea what you meant by "a coupon for the public exclusive", lol

Comment: haha, means anyone that reads this solution might be interested to buy one as i will do now. ur call

Comment: Still not sure what you mean...I don't work for JWPlayer or Flash, so can't provide anyone a coupon for anything.  Our company services are pretty well known in the educational community, but are generally a service provided for those that don't have someone like you on board.